# Excess border selection in WPF's Lisbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, grid-layout, listboxitem

My program is a sort of image picker, much like File Explorer's large image view.
I am using a ListBox with a Grid as Panel.

Problem is, the standard selection for ListBox items encompasses the entire "cell" of the grid, instead of applying only to my object (which is a Border around an Image), as shown in the image below:

[image: Example Image]

And it can get pretty silly when there is a single image:

[image: Example Image 2]

How can I do a selection that applies only to my image object, like the one in File Explorer?

Comment: Can you provide your XAML code?

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34455944/424129